# Add text to Bootstrap collapsed glyphicon links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a basic page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <style>
        body { padding-top: 70px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-3">Sidebar</div>
        <div class="col-md-9">Content</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When viewed on a small screen, as expected, the nav bar content collapses into a right-aligned button with a drop-down menu. Somewhat awkward, however, is that my envelope icon and off icon look somewhat awkward when they get collapsed into the small-screen drop-down menu. They look good, however, as simple icons with no text on the full-sized nav bar. Is there a way to have text applied to these icon links so that it will display in the collapsed menu but not in the full nav-bar? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exemple :

```
<span class="icon-bar">
       <span class="visible-phone hidden-tablet hidden-desktop">myIconLabel</span>
</span>
```

The class **visible-phone hidden-tablet hidden-desktop** will show it on phone (collapsed menu), but not on tablet or desktop.